# Replacing menu link text with image: overriding the right function?

Tags: routes, media, theming

I try to use images instead of text in main menu, in a theme I'm building. Used different solutions in my template.php, without any luck. Drupal prints the link to the image and not the image itself. I even use the suggested Drupal modules (menuicon and menuimage). But I got the same bad result.

Same kind of questions was asked here around but with no working solution for me, as far as I tried.

Yesterday, a similar question was asked on Stackoverflow and get a comment from Clive (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788449/overridden-theme-menu-link-is-not-used). Clive gave a hint on maybe this user is overriding the wrong function. But unfortunately, the question was removed by the user last night. Yes, I'm that kind of unlucky guy :-)

So, I will try to ask it myself with some posted code, hoping that someone can give me a clue to solve the issue.

Here is the code in my template.php:

```
    function caracole_menu_link($link) {
       $element = $link['element'];
       // Allows for images as menu items. Just supply the path to the image as the title
       if ( strpos($element ['#title'], '.png') !== false || strpos($element ['#title'], '.jpg') !== false || strpos($element ['#title'], '.gif') !== false) {
       $link['element']['#title'] =  '<img alt="'. $element['#original_link']['description'].'" src="'. url($link['element']['#title']) .'" title="'. $element['#original_link']['description'] .'">';
       $link['element']['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    }
    return theme_menu_link($link);
    }
```

It's one of the solutions provided on forums. But I can't get it to work for me...

best regards,

plouf

Comment: For the record my comment over there was _Your theme probably does something like this: print theme('links__system_main_menu'... to print the menu. That theme function is theme_links(), not theme_menu_link(), so you're probably just overriding the wrong function_

Comment: Thanks for posting the dissapeared comments here! By the way, i found a workaround. Wouldn't call it a solution so I will post it as a comment for now. Looks like it's overriding the right function after all: I read on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7 that theming main_menu may be tricky. So I disabled the primary menu in my theme settings and create a new menu with all the items I used in the former main menu and placed it in the same region... Worked directly and perfectly, replacing the text title with my images!

Comment: How do you define which image to show for which menu item? E.g. when you edit the menu item, where do you choose an image?

Comment: In general I prefer to render like a normal menu item with textual label, then use CSS negative text-indent and overflow:hidden on the link element. Then a CSS background image. The question is, how do you define which background image to show on which item? I can expand this to a full reply if I get more information.

Comment: @donquixote I just use the path to the image in the menu item title like "sites/all/themes/name_of_my_theme/images/image.png". And the overriding function in template.php replace this link with the actual image.

Comment: So then the menu link does not have a title at all? Generally for SEO it is preferable if it has a title, even if that is just in the alt of the image or hidden with text-indent and overflow:hidden.

Comment: What about you encode both the title and the image in the title field? E.g. with a special separator.

Comment: I guess you're right about the SEO issue. Let's see if I can use a hidden text title with text-indent or so!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using hook_preprocess_link().

Here's a snippet:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_link().
 */
function example_preprocess_link(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['path'] == 'path/of/link/to/change') {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'class-use-image';
  }
}
```

Then in your CSS file, define the class that replaces the text with the image:

```
.class-use-image {
  width: 350px; 
  height: 75px;
  background: url("images/<your-iamge>");
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

More techniques on replacing text with image [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/).